# Hacer que COUNT devuelva Cero cuando no hay resultados

Tags: oracle-12c

Tengo la siguiente consulta de donde obtengo la cantidad que hay en el stage , pero resulta que cuando no hay nada en el stage  el query omite ese cantidad, y necesito que aparezca el día pero con valor 0.

Me pueden ayudar a resolverlo? Me está dando muchos dolores de cabeza :(

La consulta es:

```
SELECT NEXTSTAGE, count(CASE WHEN USN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as QTY 
FROM sfcfa912.SFCUSN@ro_prd_wmx912  
where Line ='R1' and SUBSTR (USN,1,1) = 'R' AND NEXTSTAGE IN ('AI','AO','H1','IN','WT','TO','TN','PT','SU','WB','QN','TP','BO','CS','WP','WM','RN','RO','IO','IP') and trunc (updatetime) >= trunc (sysdate-14)
group by NEXTSTAGE
```

Comment: Bienvenido fredy ortiz toto a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna tabla maestra desde dónde obtener los  `NEXTSTAGE` ?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contexto de la consulta? Script, procedimiento, cursor? A veces es mas simple cachar la excepción `NO_DATA_FOUND`.